# Download File When Button is Clicked jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following button in my HTML:

```
<button id="exportVCardButton">Export vCard</button>
```

I have the following jQuery code that executes when the button is clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', '#exportVCardButton', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.location.href = 'contacts/createVCard.php?contactID=<?php echo $contactID; ?>';
});
```

When this button is clicked, the createVCard.php script creates a vCard and sends the file as a download to the browser. In Safari, it works just fine. However, in Google Chrome, I am getting the following error in the console:

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/x-vcard`

I have tried several different solutions but none seem to work. Does anybody have any suggestions to make the file download in Chrome as it does in Safari?

Comment: @Marc this is basically what my code does except with a button instead of a link.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know around this issue with chrome is to  specify the [HTML5 download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) inside an `<a>` tag, to use this your code would change to:

```
<a id="exportVCardButton" href="contacts/createVCard.php?contactID=<?php echo $contactID; ?>" download>Export vCard</a>
```

Or, with JQuery, perhaps something like: (Untested)

```
$(document).on('click', '#exportVCardButton', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $('#exportVCardButton').attr('href');
    document.location.href = href;
});
```

You would need to make sure you have the *href* attribute set in your link for the jQuery to work

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty simple.

`<button onclick = document.getElementById("download").click()>Download</button> <a id = "download" href="file.txt" download="file.txt"></a>`

What this does is it makes download href invisible so it doesn't show on the page. When people click the button the button clicks the invisible href, downloading the file.